# Streamwriter part of transaction

Tags: .net, transactions

Is it possible to make a streamwriter object transactional? For example, if I have a process that selects a bunch of ids from a database, then adds them to a text file and then deletes them from the database, then the three operations should be atomic.

I will add some code if this will help. I have spent time googling this as I expected to find the answer on here, but I have not.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but I should imagine that copying the text file to a temp file, working on that and only replacing the original if your DB stuff worked out OK, shouldn't be too far off.